# MVC: How to submit a Parent ViewModel inplace of a Child ViewModel form

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a QueueViewModel with a list of ItemViewModels inside. In my view Each ItemViewModel has its own
form.

```
public class QueueViewModel
{
    public List<ItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }

    public ItemViewModel SelectedItem { get; set; }

    public List<strings> ListOfStringsIneed { get; set; }

    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
}

public class ItemViewModel
{
    public int ItemID { get; set; }

    public string RandomInfo { get; set; }
}
```

When a ItemViewModel form is submitted I would like the values of that specific item to be added to the SelectedItem field of the parent QueueViewModel, then have the QueueViewModel POSTed to the controller.

What would be a good way of doing this without including the parent QueueViewModel as hidden fields in each of forms?

Answer (score 0):

You can include the parent relationship in `ItemViewModel`, like

```
public class ItemViewModel { public int QueueId { get; set; } }
```

Then in your back-end controller, you know how to create the entire parent.

The point here is to leverage from your persistence layer and take some of the load off HTTP.

Comment: I had previously been using session to store the QueueViewModel but recently the decision had been made to remove sessions. I will have to look up more information about the persistence layer as I'm unaware of it.

Comment: Your persistence layer is your database. Another option is caching on the web tier, i.e. HttpContext.Cache